# Python Multithread or Background Process?

Tags: python, multithreading

I would like to know how to optimize a link-checker which I've implemented as a webservice in Python. I already cache responses to a database which expires every 24 hours. Every night I have a cron job which refreshes the cache so the cache is effectively never out-of-date.

Things slow, of course, if I truncate the cache, or if a page is being checked that has a lot of links not in the cache. I am no computer scientist, so I'd like some advice and some concrete help on how to optimize this using either threads, or processes.

I thought of optimizing by requesting each url as a background process (pseudocodish):

```
    # The part of code that gets response codes not in cache...
    responses = {}

    # To begin, create a dict of url to process in background
    processes = {}
    for url in urls:
        processes[url] = Popen("curl " url + " &")

    # Now loop through again and get the responses
    for url in processes
        response = processes[url].communicate()
        responses[url] = response

    # Now I have responses dict which has responses keyed by url
```

This cuts down the time of the script by at least 1/6 for most of my use-cases as opposed to just looping through each url and waiting for each response, but I am concerned about overloading the server the script is running on. I considered using a queue and having batches of maybe 25 or so at a time.

Would multithreading be better overall solution? If so, how would I do this using the multithreading module?

Comment: "I would separate your website from the link checker." I'm not sure what you mean. This has nothing to do with "my website". It is a separate application. Yes, I first do a HEAD request and if that fails I send a GET request.

Comment: By "your website" I mean your frontend. Have two separate applications that communicate through a message queue or a database.